# Adding query string to multiple page urls in a Wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress function that adds a query string `'nocfcache=1'` to a single page.

```
function nocfcache_query_string( $url, $id ) {
    if( 42 == $id ) {
        $url = add_query_arg( 'nocfcache', 1, $url );
    }
    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'page_link', 'nocfcache_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

> **Issue:** How to use multiple page ids in the function so as to make sure they all have the query string appended.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
function nocfcache_query_string( $url, $id ) {
    $id = array (399, 523, 400, 634, 636, 638);
    if(in_array($post->ID, $id)) {
        $url = add_query_arg( 'nocfcache', true, get_permalink( $post->ID ));
        return $url;
        exit;
    }
}

add_filter( 'page_link', 'nocfcache_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom checkbox field/option for page/post/any (you can use ACF todo it easily).
You can use it to check if page requires to add the query string or not.

```
function nocfcache_query_string( $url, $id ) {
$custom_checkbox = get_post_meta($id, 'custom_field_name', true); // though for ACF you also use get_field('custom_field_name', $id);   
if( $custom_checkbox ) {
        $url = add_query_arg( 'nocfcache', 1, $url );
    }
    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'page_link', 'nocfcache_query_string', 10, 2 );
```